# Confusing of using pointer in Go

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I have my sample code like below.

```
type Apple struct {
    Color string
}
//In this way, the code runs just fine.
func main(){
        var test = 6
        TestTest(&test)
        fmt.Println(test)
        a := Apple{"red"}
        Eat(&a)
        fmt.Println(a.Color)
}


    func TestTest(num *int) {
        *num = *num + 2
    }
    func Eat(a *Apple) {
        a.Color = "green"
    }
```

the question is, why do I have to put a star(*) before a `num` variable but not for `a.Color`? 
If I do so to `a.Color`, it says

> invalid indirect of a.Color (type string)

or if I remove a star(*) from `num`, it says

> invalid operation: num + 2 (mismatched types *int and int)

that makes me confused, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are two different cases:

**Case1**

`num` is a pointer to int, So you need to add the integer value to the value stored at address pointed by `num`. Hence you are dereferencing the `num` pointer to get the value stored inside it as:

```
func TestTest(num *int) {
    *num = *num + 2 // dereference the pointer to get the value.
}
```

**Case2**

you are assigning a string value to Color field of Apple struct which is not a pointer. But you are using the pointer to the struct not to the field. That's why you are able to assign a value like this:

```
func Eat(a *Apple) { // a is the pointer to struct.
    a.Color = "green"
}
```

Now if you want to generate the same error which is you are getting in first case, create a pointer type Color field inside the struct as:

```
type Apple struct {
    Color *string // this is the pointer value which will throw the same error in your current implementation.
}
```

Error code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dTEap7u5Ixn) when trying to assign a pointer type value to a non-pointer variable when using struct.

**Solution**

To set the value in case you are using pointer field in a struct use reflection as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

//I have my sample code like this.

type Apple struct {
    Color *string
}

//In this way, the code runs just fine.
func main() {
    var test = 6
    TestTest(&test)
    fmt.Println(test)
    point := "red"
    a := Apple{&point}
    Eat(&a)
    fmt.Println(a.Color)
}

func TestTest(num *int) {
    *num = *num + 2
}
func Eat(a *Apple) {
    str := "green"
    r := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    elm := r.Elem().FieldByName("Color")
    elm.Set(reflect.ValueOf(&str))
    fmt.Printf("%+v", (*a).Color)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6_TpdP7TfBq) Example

One more thing to notice is the value of reflection is actually `reflect.Ptr` so what we can do is we can loop over the struct fields to get the value and then use `reflect.Indirect` to get the value of the pointer type color field.

```
func Eat(a *Apple) {
    str := "green"
    r := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    elm := r.FieldByName("Color")
    elm.Set(reflect.ValueOf(&str))
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", (*a).Color)
    for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
        valueField := r.Field(i)
        fmt.Println(reflect.Indirect(valueField))
    }
    // or use FieldByName to get the value of a field.
    st := "Color"
    fmt.Println(reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem().FieldByName(st)))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because Go automatically dereferences a pointer before dot property.

You can also do it manually by:

```
(*a).Color = "green"
```

Your code failed probably because you didn't use the parenthese and it tries to dereference Color property instead of a itself.